# 802.1x with Hyper-V

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v, 802.1x

We are using 802.1x authentication inside the corporate network. When I installed HyperV Virtual Switch on my machine to let the VM into the network, the host lost its network connectivity.

I came upon a post on an MS support forum that 802.1x with Hyper-V is officially not supported by Windows 8.1. Apparently, the same problem exists on Windows 10.

**How can one use Hyper-V VM and have connectivity for both host and VM in case of 802.1x authentication policy in the network?**

Answer (score 0):

According to [Jeff Woolsey on windowsserver.uservoice.com](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/295050-virtualization/suggestions/8619418-let-hyper-v-virtual-switch-forward-802-1x-authenti), 802.1x support has been added:

> In Windows Server 2019 & Windows 10 version 1809 & later we added
> support for 802.1x through the Hyper-V vSwitch. While many customers
> use IPSEC for transparent E2E network encryption, some still use
> 802.1×.
>
> To enable 802.1x, run the following from an elevated command prompt:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\vmsmp\parameters" /v 8021xEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
shutdown /r /t 0
```

[Further write-up by Didier Van Hoye on WorkingHardInIt.work blog](https://blog.workinghardinit.work/2019/01/17/802-1x-support-with-the-hyper-v-switch-is-here/).