# Docker for Windows / Hyper-V with 802.1x authentication

Tags: networking, hyper-v, docker, 802.1x, docker-for-windows

After installing [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) on my Windows 10 Enterprise (1607) machine, I can no longer authenticate onto the 802.1X-enabled wired network.

This seems to be related to Docker for Windows's dependency on Hyper-V. Disabling the `Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter` in Device Manager makes authentication work again, and the connection keeps working if I then enable the Hyper-V adapter again. So that seems to be an effective workaround, though not very convenient.

Does anyone know of a real fix for this issue?

Comment: Probably-related question: https://superuser.com/questions/1043936/802-1x-with-hyper-v